# TabEnter event not caught with mouse click

Tags: vim

I have this in .vimrc:

autocmd TabEnter * call Foo()
or just
autocmd TabEnter * echo "Got TabEnter Event"

However this is invoked only if I do :tabn or :tabp. When I click on the tab it does not invoke Foo. Any ideas on how to make this work or alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick test here showed that it works.

Maybe it is just that you can't see the echo message. Try using `:echom`:

```
:autocmd TabEnter * echom "Got TabEnter Event"
```

Then you can use `:messages` to check the messages, even those that may have been cleared from you screen by some other event/message.

Another approach to check is to increment a global variable inside your `Foo()` function and `:echo` its value after changing tabpages with command and mouse.

Comment: Thanks, echom is good way to check. My Foo is doing some stuff which does not work somehow when clicked with mouse, but works with tabn/p